# simplified key-mouse: inputs

Tags: python, pygame

Im thinking of writing a simplified class for the pygame events class but im not quite sure on how i would go about this.

I want to simply check if a key or mouse has been pressed for example without the long winded forloop over events:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
        //do something
```

Instead I Would like

```
if keydown(K_ESCAPE):
   //do something
```

But Im really unsure on how to go about this.

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

To write the function you describe:

```
def keydown(event, *keys):
    return event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key in keys
```

then you can call it:

```
 if keydown(event, K_ESCAPE):
```

You can pass multiple keys as successive positional arguments.

Comment: But if i do this, i have to define event. I just want if keydown(K_ESCAPE). How do i do this?

Comment: How would you do this with mouse input too?

Comment: You could encapsulate the `event.get` loop in your function, too, but you will need to think about how you deal with quit. For mouse input, [read the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Answer (score 0):

You still need a for loop, but if you want simplified event handling you may find this code useful (in particular, the `EventHandle` class and `eventLoop()`): https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~freevial/freevial/trunk/view/head:/src/common/events.py

An usage example is [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~freevial/freevial/trunk/view/head:/src/selcat.py) in method `juguem()':

```
for event in eventLoop():

    if event.keyUp('q', 'ESCAPE', 'KP_ENTER', 'F3', 'F5') or \
    event.keyUp('RETURN') and estat != 0:
        return

    if event.keyUp('DOWN'):
        pass # do something
```